# Is there a way to config merging pull request only after at least two approval for Github?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I want to ask github to detect if a pull request has two approval. If it does not, the merge will be rejected. Is there a way to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the [GitHub Review API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/reviews/) in order to list the reviews on a PR:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/reviews
```

That can be part on a [webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) that you manage, triggered on [pull-request review event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestreviewevent).

If you detect 2 reviews, you call the [PR API for merging](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button).

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:number/merge
```

So in short, I don't think you can ask directly GitHub for that feature, but you can implement it as a webhook.